# package org.pdfbox.cos does not exist

Tags: java, pdfbox, drjava

I am trying to import and use PDFBox, but am having issues installing the jars I believe.

I am using Dr. Java, and I have added both the pdfbox-1.8.6.jar and the pdfbox-app-1.8.6.jar to my resource locations in my Extra Classpath.

However, it still is not recognizing the jars when I run the code:

```
import org.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
```

What other steps do I need to do in order for the jars to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the correct imports:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
```

Additional hints:

- pdfbox-app-1.8.6.jar contains the classes from pdfbox-1.8.6.jar, so you don't need pdfbox-1.8.6.jar too
- if you want to load a document for rendering or text extraction, you won't need these two imports. Loading is done with

  import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

  PDDocument doc = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(filename), null);

To see how it is done, look at the examples in the source code. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the steps detailed on the documentation:

**Adding And Removing JARs in DrJava**

> A JAR file is a way of storing many (pre-compiled) Java classes. Below
>   are instructions for adding and removing jar files from DrJava's
>   resource locations. For more information on JAR files, see our JARs
>   page and Using JAR Files: The Basics on Sun's site.

**How to add a JAR**

1. When you download the jar, keep track of where you save it to
2. Open DrJava
3. Edit > Preferences
4. Resource Locations (at left)
5. In Extra Classpath, Add (browse and chose the new jar)
6. Apply
7. Okay
8. Quit DrJava and re-open it in order for the change to take effect

[image]

Comment: Used those exact installation instructions

Comment: @Connor have you tried [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)